# How can I configure a network interface to be available to a VirtualBox guest and be unused by the host?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-10.10, network-interface

On a host system with two physical network interfaces, how can I designate one interface to be used *only* by a VirtualBox guest OS?

Both host and guest are Ubuntu 10.10 running NetworkManager. Ideally, I would like the designated network interface to be managed by NetworkManager in the guest and be unknown to NetworkManager in the host.

Answer (score 0):

Take it out of nm managed interfaces on the host.  Set it to bridged in vbox.  If it gets used in the client great, if not that's great too.

edit: it might be required that the "client only" interface is in promisc on the host

Comment: Rather than insult my question and complain about your inability to type international characters, it might benefit your cause to indicate to both myself and other readers what ambiguity in my question is causing you such difficulty.

Comment: The ambiguity is that it's obviously possible...hence my "is this really a question" comment.  There are a bunch of side-issues that could come into play, like arp caching from the "unused" interface if it isn't in promiscuous mode.  There are obvious possibilities for routing issues(can't have similar IP address ranges on both interfaces or something will probably get screwy).  The statement is it possible implies several questions: How do I place an interface in promisc mode, how do I set vbox to bridged networking, how do I enable proxy arp if req, will the host learn from client arps, etc

Comment: Thank you for explaining your interpretation. I have updated the question in a way that I feel removes the ambiguity. Please let me know or edit the question yourself if you feel that any other changes are necessary.

Comment: Good deal.  That's a much better question.  I deleted the most snide of my remarks in the comments section(just so you know).  I try not to ask questions at all, but when I do I make sure they cannot be answered yes or no.

Comment: @ændrük I can type international characters btw, I just wouldn't post on a German or Russian forum using the US 101 layout character set.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is yes, but I may be confusing it with another Virtualisation product.

I would start by editing the /etc/interfaces file in the host, so that it cannot see the hardware.

The hardware does have to be known to VB. I think bridged should work just fine.

Then your guest can act as a firewall for all the network attached to the other lan card.