# VitrualBox Guest that uses NAT but gets it's own IP from DHCP and can still see BOTH Host interfaces

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, debian

i have a Windoze host and a Debian guest.  currently i have the guest network setup on a NAT, which allows me to see/use everything i need to on both host interfaces.  BUT it is one-way.  due to the NAT, it isn't pulling an IP from the DHCP, which i need to be able to have the guest reachable from *other* network assets on BOTH host interfaces (..1.0/24 and ..0.0/24).

i tried [this 'solution'](https://serverfault.com/questions/225155/virtualbox-how-to-set-up-networking-so-both-host-and-guest-can-access-internet) to start, and it failed horribly.  and i read [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/234028/how-can-i-configure-a-network-interface-to-be-available-to-a-virtualbox-guest-an) to try for some inspiration on possible options, but it led me nowhere useful to this issue.

here's a diagram of what i need:

[image]

please note that traffic is bi-directional between host/guest and subnets, but does NOT pass traffic from interface to interface.  so assets on the eth0 subnets can see host and guest, but nothing on eth0, and assets on eth1 can see host and guest, but nothing on eth0.  i hope this makes sense.  i've been forking with this for a few days now and not having any luck.  help is much needed at this point.

Comment: To be frank, it's not at all clear what you have actually tried. Also, no one can tell how you might have done it wrongly (or even, help in general) when attempting the probably-correct solution, if all you can provide is "I've tried it all and they failed horribly and now I'm at a dead end". Normally you if want a VM to be in the same subnet / broadcast domain as the host's LAN(s) you set up bridged networking, unless there are specific concerns / limitations.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to say in the last paragraph as well. Are you trying to say that you *do want* the two physical LAN to *remain isolated*, or are you trying to set up the VM as some gateway so that the two LAN can talk to each other via the VM?

Comment: @TomYan *remain isolated*.  as i said, i do not want traffic to pass from one interface to the other.  and i did explain what i tried.  did you follow the links i posted?  i also said what my current configuration is.

Answer (score 1):

> it isn't pulling an IP from the DHCP, which i need to be able to have
> the guest reachable from other network assets on BOTH host interfaces

Based on your post and diagram, you need to change your guest network from NAT to Bridged.  Bridged Network will get DHCP from your router and allow you to access the guest from both local and remote computers. I do that here.

NAT is the default network type, but here, Bridged will serve you better.

Comment: if i do that, the guest can no longer see assets on the closed network (..0.0/24 on eth0) and the assets on that closed network (..0.0/24 on eth0) still can't see the guest.